# Vertically scale server in cloud without restart

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, scalability, ovh

For a current project of mine I need a cloud service which can (automatically) scale VMs vertically as the workload can not be scaled horizontally.

With scaling I mean assigning more RAM and/or CPU cores to a given instance.

This has to happen without requiring a restart.

Are there any cloud providers that offer such a service? When researching I found VMware vCloud Air which apparently had such a feature, until it was bought (and shut down?) by OVH.

Comment: I can confirm that AWS can not do this. I haven't heard of Azure doing it but I'm not an expert. I suspect you'll need either on-premise VMWare or similar, or to go with horizontal scaling. You could use a load balancer to scale to a larger instance then turn the first instance off if your application can't scale horizontally, they're both turned on for maybe 5 minutes.

Comment: Basically: VM can't be scaled without restart, containers can (limited by the size of the physical cluster of course).
AWS offers that through Fargate, but you can't choose the ressources assigned, it scales automatically and therefore brings somme other challenges